# MySQL Worckbrench incompatible/nonstandard server version or connection protocol detectec

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

estoy experimentando con el Wockbrench, instale el 8.0, y me da error al querer acceder al localhost, avisándome que tengo una versión vieja del MySQL.  Yo tengo el MySQL que instala el PHPMyAdmint (versión 5.1).  Aparentemente tengo que tener instalado el MySQL Server, pero ese, tengo entendido que es pago.  Alguien entiende algo de esto?  Sinó, instalo el Workbrench 6.3 y listo.  Gracias Totales!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo solucioné.  Le di **"Continue Anyway"** y luego en el menú de la izquierda, abajo, hay que cambiar de **"Administration"** a **"Schemas"** y listo, aparecieron las bases de datos con sus tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que me pasó lo mismo que a ti... y bueno... me sirvió mucho tu comentario... gracias...